# Android Studio Not Lauching

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

Launching Android Studio on Ubuntu, only the Tip of the Day window shows up upon first launch. 
To launch android studio.

```
cd mypath/android-studio/bin
./studio.sh
```

Then as the Android Studio IDE launches, I see the loading bar like below.

[image: Initial Android Loading]

Then, the IDE actually begins to load like this,

[image: IDE Loading]

Only to have it disappear on me leaving me with a Tip of the Day Window with my desktop background.

[image]

On the Ubuntu Taskbar, I see the Android Studio Icon.

[image]

But clicking it and trying to open it results in no activity.

I would prefer not to uninstall and install Android Studio again, and hope for some insights to why this problem occurs.
No configurations have been done during the time the PC was shutoff to opening Android Studio again in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

It just got minimalised. Try to maximilize this with `alt` + `tab` or from all opened windows `cmd(windows key, super)` + `tab`

Comment: That is what I thought, but alt+tab doesn't do anything for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't do anything because it doesn't show Android Studio in opened applications or no apps are shown?

Comment: So when I alt+tab, I see the android studio icon in the list of opened applications, when I move to the selected icon, the window does not appear. I think it just got minimized to nothing. After selecting it with alt+tab, an alt+space gave me the options to minmize/maximize/move/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Domin was right about it being minimized!

Although alt+tab didn't do anything for me, after selecting the Android Studio Icon, I used the alt+space command and selected maximize. And the IDE appeared again!

Comment: if it's working you can accept my answer as problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove existing entry then do the following steps

Go to **Android Studio -> Tools -> Create Desktop Entry**

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about.... but I fixed my problem already thanks!

Comment: Ok good to hear it. just forget about it. I said that way to create desktop entry